# C# reference to type component claims it is defined in system, but it is not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, uwp, oledbconnection

I am developing an application (blank solution) to read, write ,and edit data in an access database file.

I created an OleDbConnection object and gave it a connection string that worked in another Console application solution.

However, when I open or close the connection, I get the error
"Cs7069 reference to type component claims it is defined in system, but it is not found"

```
  OleDbConnection a = new OleDbConnection();
//given connection string
a.Open();
a.Close();
```

I get the error when I call the Open() and the Close() methods. The error happens at compile time not runtime. [Visual studio 2015]

I tried:
Rebuilding the solution
Changing a variety of references
Cleaning then rebuilding the solution

Note: I have only one project in the solution

Please help,
Thank you

Comment: C# isn't case-insensitive. It's `Open()` and `Close()`...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer that must be a typo, the compile time error wouldn't give you the message shown in the OP. And by the way, what's up with the double negation? Isn't easier to simply say c# is case sensitive? I actually had to read it twice to make sure you were saying it right ;)

Comment: @InBetween Vengance! ;D

Comment: @user6019827 Ok, you should provide snippets that can be compiled!

Comment: It's almost always a bad idea to ask a question on a phone, where you're not in a position to check it as well as on a laptop/desktop. Please remember that the purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of high quality questions and answers - asking a good question takes time, and is best done on the right device.

Comment: Sorry, it is just that my internet plan is on phone not laptop, sure I can open hotspot and use the laptop, but figured it would be the same. I have my laptop beside me to check and try everything :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me do some guessing.

Are you building an UWP app? If so, you just cannot use OleDbConnection, there is only this [.NET subset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185501.aspx) for you.

If no and your app is not UWP, then can you reproduce error by creating empty console project, adding System.Data to references and creating minimal program to reproduce, like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection{ConnectionString = ".. your connection string .."})
        {
            connection.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("DataSource: {0}, database: {1}",connection.DataSource, connection.Database);
        }         
    }
}
```

And last and least possible, this error also can be caused by you having multiple assemblies with names mimicking System.Data, but i bet that's not your case.

Comment: I believe that it's a bad attemp to solve the issue. Your reasoning could also be applied to portable libraries, or even the old Compact Framework! Or Xamarin... Or.... Or... I would drop this answer and I would comment out if OP is using UWP...

Comment: This was my best guess taking that OP is developing bank app (so mobile, embedded less probable). Let's wait to see what OP answers

Comment: If you're in the right track, I feel that OP should tag the question with [uwp]...

Comment: Yes, it is an UWP app. If that is the case, what can I use to work with microsoft office programs?

Comment: In console application and Forms application: everything works well

Comment: Do you really need an UWP app (e.g. it should run on Win10 & Win Mobile?). Maybe what you wanted is WPF project, for windows desktop-only app? (I'm again guessing here, but..)